# How to handle google and yahoo one-click unsub law if you don't want a subkey to get unsub from all Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability, unsubscribe, google

As per standards, we'll see a one-click unsub on the email being rendered by ISPs. And in MC it's the allSubscribers list select. If you click the one-click unsub you'll get unsub from everything. But the law says the company can only unsub you from that list aka we can't send email to the same person from the same list if they unsub.

1. My thought is to use the Publication list but how other companies are handling this?
2. Also, I have a big question about how this information will float to Salesforce (if possible real-time)
3. On the other side our custom preference center updates Salesforce (MCC connect) for unsub a contact (fields with a boolean data type for unsub/re-sub). So how this data will get updated inside the point #1 publication list both the system has same information (and real-time if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use lists, especially not if your consent system of records is outside of SFMC. Then ensuring your consent status is in sync, utilising (in your case) Marketing Cloud Connect and Synchronised Data Extensions is the main place to manage your consents.

Unsubscribes generated via list-unsubscribe header are all unique to the email and recipient. Even though it goes directly to SFMC from ISP, it holds info on subscriber, job, batch etc. This allows you to map it to e.g. the email name the unsub originated from, and see e.g. which brand, service or similar it belongs to. Assuming you are sending three types of emails, let's say: flight offers, hotel offers and cruise offers, you can revoke consent for the subscriber, specific to the email received. If you can see the job ID it came from was related to the Cruise_Spotlight_2024_Spring email (by joining job data view on unsubscribes data view), you simply revoke the consent for cruise offers.

As the unsub event also changed the subscriber status to unsubscribed, it will be a good idea to change it to Active, after revoking the consent status in system of record - assuming the subscriber still has other active opt-ins.

That said... If I look at the list-unsubscribe from a subscriber point of view, I see it as an "emergency brake". This person does not care about your, otherwise presumably fantastic, preference center - where he can pick and choose the different communication types: flight offers, hotel offers and cruise offers. This person is thinking: I had it, no more emails from you mister holiday marketer!

Hence my recommendation, which also comes with reduced complexity (as you don't have to "guess" which consent to revoke), is to see this as a global unsubscribe, revoking all consents. At least for the email channel.